Почему не запрашивает разрешение на уведомление pwa-push- ios?
Делаю pwa-приложение, и хочу пихнуть push-уведомление, но при заходе на сайт, только через комп или андроид - запрашивается разрешение на уведомление, но вот именно на IOS почему-то не хочет... пробовал вывести ошибку, но там пустота


navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw4.js").then(
                        async function (registration) {
                            console.log(
                                "ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",
                                registration.scope
                            );
                            registerForPushNotifications(registration);
                        },
                        function (err) {
                            console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", err);
                        }
                    );

 async function registerForPushNotifications(registration) {
            try {
                const pushServerPublicKey = "КЛЮЧ";
                // subscribe and return the subscription
                const subscription = await registration.pushManager
                    .subscribe({
                        userVisibleOnly: true,
                        applicationServerKey: pushServerPublicKey,
                    })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Failed to subscribe to push notifications:', err);
            }
        }



